Nombres de las distintas notaciones en EER
Estoy unificando un temario de BD. Me gustaría poder nombrar y comparar todas las notaciones que hay para las cardinalidades máxima y mínima, también llamadas cardinalidad y participación.
En la siguiente imagen tengo una comparativa pero no indica el nombre de la notación. Además de estas, ¿me podéis indicar otras que haya? Gracias

Tengo entendido que la 3ª sería Chen o clásica. La 4ª sería ADW.
La fuente de la imagen es https://bookdown.org/paranedagarcia/database/modelamiento-de-datos-1.html

Tus ultimas 5 preguntas, no demuestran que estes haciendo una investigacion al respecto.. podrias por favor decir de donde sale cada una de esas notaciones y que investigaste al respecto? una de tus dudas, por ejemplo, estaba respondida ya en el sitio en ingles... Esta bien que preguntes, pero por la cantidad de tus preguntas y que todas son similares, suena a que nos falta una pata de lo que necesitas... es mas, la mayoria son muy similares entre si...

La verdad que pensaba que este lugar era para hacer preguntas y que personas con más conocimientos te ayudasen con las respuestas. Tengo más feedback sobre la mala calidad de mis preguntas que respuestas a lo que necesito. Espero no te lo tomes a mal, pero si he llegado aquí es por lo agotado que estoy de buscar por internet y encontrarme todo tipo de respuestas que no me dan ninguna seguridad. Este lugar parece el sitio correcto, pero me estoy encontrando que están más pendientes de mi forma de formular las preguntas que de ofrecerme respuestas.

Con respecto a la respuesta en inglés que me facilitaste, no me da ninguna seguridad. Hay tantas formas de enfocarlo como respuestas. Así que sigo buscando otras fuentes que me den mayor seguridad. Si hago preguntas similares, es a raíz de vuestras inquietudes de que mis preguntas no son correctas, así que eso es lo que estoy intentando. Mi intención es el conocimiento, no vengo aquí a molestar ni ofender a nadie.

Para nada estas ni molestando ni ofendiendo a nadie. Al reves, estamos tratando de guiarte en lo que necesitas, pero para eso, tenemos que saber que averiguaste ya y que sabes, para no darte la misma respuesta que ya tenes. Los temas que estas tratando son tan poco estandar, que basicamente cualquiera puede hacerlo como quiere, y no esta mal...

No entiendo como una respuesta no te da ninguna seguridad. Que tipo de respuesta te daria seguridad, sobre un tema que no esta ni normado, ni reglado, y que cualquiera puede hacer como quiere? fijate que tenes un monton de nomenclaturas para indicar exactamente lo mismo, y que puede que ni siquiera tengan un nombre...

Estoy preparando unos apuntes para un alumnado bastante exigente. No querría decir nada que no tenga la seguridad de que sea 100% correcto. De ahí que acuda a esta fuente. A buscar más seguridad que la que me han dado mis búsquedas de google así como libros versados en la materia. Entiendo perfectamente que es un tema que no está normativizado, pero me gustaría que los nombres que le pongo a las cosas, así como lo que escribo en esos apuntes tenga visos de realidad, no que me parezca que lo estoy improvisando o negando cosas que, realmente son ciertas.

Por ejemplo. La notación pata de gallo la hizo famosa Martin. He visto por ahí fuentes que dicen notación de MArtin. Cuando lo vi por primera vez, pensé que era otra. Y, resulta, que no. Que es la misma. Simplemente como él fue el que la hizo famosa pues muchos la llama o la conocen por él y no como pata de gallo. Este simple dato me llevó unas horas atestiguarlo.

Ok, se entiende.. pero tambien entiendes que las respuestas dadas en este sitio pueden no tener un fundamento universal, asi como las que viste en ingles? O sea.. al no estar normado, estas buscando que un NN, en una pagina, te diga, se llama asi.. porque deberias creerle a ese NN mas que a una pagina en particular? Que te hace dudar por ejemplo de la respuesta que esta en ingles?? que no tiene referencias? Estoy tratando de guiarte, que tal vez no estes buscando algo que tenga respuesta asi firme... A veces, en sistemas, no hay nada seguro, inclusive cambiando de paises ;)

La respuesta que me enviaste, en inglés, ya la había localizado antes buscando por google. Cada uno interpreta el sólo 1, y el uno y solo 1, como les da la gana. Unos dicen que son lo mismo. Otros que el solo 1 sirve para cuando el mínimo no lo tienes claro, y partes de un dibujo a medias. Otros que son cosas diferentes, como que 1 y solo 1, es que sólo una entidad del conjunto puede relacionarse, el resto de entidades no puede ni relacionarse. Estas son 3 de las opciones o ideas que he visto. Como comprenderás, no me dan ninguna seguridad.

Hay hasta tres teorías diferentes ;). De ahí que siga buscando. Me gustaría saber si es cuestión, por ejemplo, de escuelas. Como usar diferentes notaciones, pues cada notación dice lo mismo que otra, pero con caracteres diferentes. Pero esto del solo 1 vs 1 y solo 1, ya no son sólo diferentes notaciones. Es que hay gente que dice que son cardinalidades diferentes. Ahora espero comprendas, el por qué sigo indagando. Muchas gracias por preocuparte en ayudarme.

Si habias localizado esa respuesta, lo tendrias que haber aclarado, si no, estamos buscando y dandote como respuesta algo que ya tenes como respuesta. Ahora entendes porque es importante saber que buscaste y como? yo perdi tiempo (el mio) buscandote informacion (que ya sabias) y para colmo, ni siquiera recibi feedback tuyo al respecto... Es por eso que molestamos y nos importan la calidad de como preguntas, para no hacer el mismo trabajo mas de una vez.

Tambien, si hay teorias, es porque basicamente no hay un standard, y como lo has visto, nadie, pero nadie, tiene una respuesta correcta. Todas son correctas, porque basicamente, a nadie le importa. Las dos versiones del 1 a n, nunca las habia visto.. si hay 1, hay 1.. no hay forma de que sea mas de 1.. si me das un ejemplo practico de los dos casos, te creo, pero me suena a sobreingenieria de un caso muy pero muy particular... No se cual es tu expertise en todo esto, y yo no soy teorico.. pero en la practica, a nadie le importa mientras digas que es cada simbolo...

Ok. Por mi parte lo dejamos aquí. No vengo a debatir cómo hacer una pregunta, como responderla, como escribir, qué decir. Vengo a por conocimiento. ¿Te parece que otros me ayuden y tú te dedicas a "ayudar" a otros?. Gracias. No gastes más tiempo conmigo.

Por desgracia, mientras reporten tus preguntas, tengo que seguir "ayudandote".. el simbolito que ves al lado de mi nombre, es por algo.. pero no te preocupes.. sigue intentando conseguir tu respuesta.. solo no repitas preguntas, se claro y por favor, indica todo lo que sabes en cada pregunta...
